# How to call variable in javascript using telnet

Tags: javascript, html, css, telnet

I have a website that consists of multiple pages. My website is not hosted and is viewed through xampp localhost. I want to know how would I call variables to change the color to red when Mute is received and green when MuteOn is received from a remote telnet for the icons code below labeled icon. Also is is my current telnet javascript connection code. I ultimately would like for my server.js to have the function to receive commands and then implement them to my webpage.

Server.js:

```
// Include Nodejs' net module.
const Net = require('net');
// The port on which the server is listening.
const port = 50000;
// Use net.createServer() in your code. This is just for illustration purpose.
// Create a new TCP server.
const server = new Net.Server();
// The server listens to a socket for a client to make a connection request.
// Think of a socket as an end point.
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`Server listening for connection requests on socket localhost:${port}`.);
});
// When a client requests a connection with the server, the server creates a new
// socket dedicated to that client.
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A new connection has been established.');
    // Now that a TCP connection has been established, the server can send data to
    // the client by writing to its socket.
    socket.write('Hello, client.');
    // The server can also receive data from the client by reading from its socket.
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(`Data received from client: ${chunk.toString()`.});
    });
    // When the client requests to end the TCP connection with the server, the server
    // ends the connection.
    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Closing connection with the client');
    });
    // Don't forget to catch error, for your own sake.
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
});
```

Icon code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-w flex-c-m p-t-5 p-b-0">
<a href="#" class="flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-50 m-l-50 m-b-5">
<i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:95px;color:white'></i>
</a>

<a href="#" class="flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-50 m-l-50 m-b-5">
<i class='fas fa-microphone' style='font-size:95px;color:white'></i>
</a>

<a href="#" class="flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-50 m-l-50 m-b-5">
<i class='fas fa-phone-volume' style='font-size:95px;color:white'></i>
</a>

<a href="#" class="flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-50 m-l-50 m-b-5">
<i class='fas fa-video' style='font-size:95px;color:white'></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I used html, css, and javascript when designing this webpage. I am fairly new to using telnet so all information is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So the operation of your site doesn't not involve HTTP and the browser at all?

Comment: It does, I run it on google chrome through a localhost. Hope this helps @AvivLo

Comment: You'll need something like express to twick and serve the html

Comment: No ptoblem.  Should I add to the answer?

Comment: Yes, please @AvivLo

Answer (score 2):

You'll need something like express to tweak and serve the HTML. Telnet is using TCP protocol which is different from the HTTP protocol.